# get a specific ancestor of a html element using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Say for example I have the following markup:

```
<article>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Article Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <div class="details">
            <span class="category-info">X</span>
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>

<article>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Article Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum...</p>
        <div class="details">
            <ul>
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

and I want to remove any article which contains a `.category-info`

```
$(".category-info").parent().parent().parent().remove();
```

Is there a better way than to call `.parent().parent().parent()` to move up the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better approach would be to use the [`:has()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) in order to select `article` elements that have `.category-info` descendant elements:

```
$('article:has(.category-info)').remove();
```

---

Alternatively, you could also use the [`.closest()` method](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) and avoid chaining the `.parent()` method multiple times:

```
$('.category-info').closest('article').remove();
```

This will select the closest `article` ancestor of the `.category-info` element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `has()` jQuery API like following code :

```
$('article').has('.category-info').remove();
```

You might need to read this [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
$(".category-info").closest("article").remove();
```